# Batch File - scanning a source directory (folderA) for source file, then copying files with same file name from folder B to folder C

Tags: batch-file

I'm very new to basic programming and have run into a wall on a task I'm trying to automate. I've found some things that I have been able to use, but this question is fairly specific and I haven't found something that quite works.

I'm using Sorenson Squeeze to encode video files into different formats. As part of the automated watch folder process Sorenson will place a source file in a "CompletedSource" folder when it is done encoding. What I would like to do is create a batch file that can be scheduled to run hourly that only copies the various encoded files from the "Done" folder to a third directory only if a file with the same name exists in the "CompletedSource" folder. This is to avoid using a scheduled batch file that just copies all files from "Done" to the archive including files that are currently being processed. I just want to copy "complete" files.

For example (when Sorenson has fully completed the encoding job):

CompletedSource folder will contain

> 12345.mov (or .mp4)

Done folder will contain

> 12345_hd.mov, 12345_high.mov, 12345_high.mp4, 12345_med.mp4, 12345_low.mp4

I want to copy all `.mov` files in "Done" to a "Quicktime" folder and copy all `.mp4` files to a "MP4" folder.

I've tried testing with the below which looks like it should work for the MP4 copy:

```
for %%F in ("C:\test\Done\\*.mp4") do if exist "C:\test\CompletedSource\%%~nF.*" echo copy "%%F" "C:\test\MP4"
```

However, when I remove the echo it doesn't actually copy the files.

Comment: Why the doubled back slash before the file mask? `C:\test\Done\\*.mp4`

Comment: The preview here was cutting out the lone slash to make it look like "C:\test\Done*.mp4" instead of "C:\test\Done\*.mp4" when I was first typing this up. The test code I'm using only has one slash there.

Answer (score 0):

```
...echo Xcopy "C:\test\CompletedSource\%%~nF.*" "C:\test\MP4\"
```

which should copy all of the files matching the source-mask from the specified directory to a directory named `...MP4`.

`XCOPY` will make the destination directory if it needs to, then copy according to the mask.

You don't mention any error messages created. Saying merely that it doesn't do what it's supposed to do unfortunately isn't particularly useful. We know that because if it did, you wouldn't have posted your question.

Comment: When running the batch file after removing "echo" it doesn't give any errors, it just displays the below:
C:\test>for %F in ("C:\test\Done\*.mp4") do if exist "C:\test\CompletedSource\%~
nF.*" xcopy "%F" "C:\test\MP4\"

C:\test>if exist "C:\test\CompletedSource\12345_high.*" xcopy "C:\test\Done\1234
5_high.mp4" "C:\test\MP4\"

C:\test>if exist "C:\test\CompletedSource\12345_low.*" xcopy "C:\test\Done\12345
_low.mp4" "C:\test\MP4\"

C:\test>if exist "C:\test\CompletedSource\12345_med.*" xcopy "C:\test\Done\12345
_med.mp4" "C:\test\MP4\"
C:\test>pause1>nul